# Run a shell script on boot in ubuntu

Tags: shell, boot

I've done a shell that print on therminal: "Welcome Davide, have a nice day". This script i want that start on boot. I've tryed to put it everywhere but nothing . The folders i put it are: rc6.d and rc0.d. Then i wrote the whole script in rc.local but nothing happen..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you want it to run at the time of login. Put it in `.bashrc`

If you want to see it before login to tty0-tty6, put the text "Welcome Davide, have a nice day" in `/etc/issue`.

[Adition by fedorqui]: If you want it to be displayed on tty0-6 AFTER login, put it in `/etc/motd`. This will not show up when running from ssh.

Comment: Also `/etc/motd`, that stands for Message Of The Day.

Comment: ^^ Oh... interesting... :)