# In the mac terminal, what is the bash shell event for when the computer wakes up or starts?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I'm trying to make a terminal script that says something when you open the computer. I do not know the bash event for when the computer wakes up. Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run a shell script on boot in ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901280/run-a-shell-script-on-boot-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [SleepWatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/) utility. First of all, download the package and extract it:

```
curl --remote-name "http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/sleepwatcher_2.2.tgz"
tar xvzf sleepwatcher_2.2.tgz 2>/dev/null
cd sleepwatcher_2.2
```

Then copy the files to the proper locations:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/share/man/man8
$ sudo cp sleepwatcher /usr/local/sbin
$ sudo cp sleepwatcher.8 /usr/local/share/man/man8
```

Copy and load the launch script to make sure SleepWatcher starts on boot:

```
sudo cp config/de.bernhard-baehr.sleepwatcher-20compatibility.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/de.bernhard-baehr.sleepwatcher.plist
sudo launchctl load -w -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/de.bernhard-baehr.sleepwatcher.plist
```

You can then add your scripts to `/etc/rc.wakeup` and `/etc/rc.sleep`:

```
sudo touch /etc/rc.wakeup
sudo touch /etc/rc.sleep
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.sleep /etc/rc.wakeup
```

You can find more details in ReadMe.rtf (can be found in the root of the package) and in the blog post [Sleepwatcher : Run Script on Sleep](http://tyhoffman.com/blog/2013/09/sleepwatcher-power-event-driven-automation/). You can also find a script in this blog post which will run all the necessary commands for you.